# Multiple content types in one template with Umbraco.ModelsBuilder

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

We have multiple base content types `News`, `Reviews`. Each inherit properties from our composites: `_Page` & `_Article`. This allows us to wack all three content types into a single article template.

Currently using `IPublishedContent`, means we have something like:

```
    if (Model.Content.DocumentTypeAlias == "review") 
    { 
        // ... Do This 
    }
```

With ModelsBuilder, we can't do this anymore.

The result is models looking like this:

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2fY.png)

Tried to do: `@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.IArticle>`, but this means I lose all my other properties.

**What model would you inherit for a template using multiple content types, or is there something else we need to do?**

*A note on this: I would love to do _Page > _Article > ContentType, but it would mean huge data loss.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `@inherits UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.IArticle>`, then you could do something like `var review = Model as Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Review`. if `review` is not null, you know that the page is of type `Review`.

(By the way, cant remember if it needs to be `Model.Content` you do the cast on.)

Comment: Hero. This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

While you are free to inherit Razor templates from a ModelsBuilder class, generally most, in my experience are using ModelsBuilder to help hydrate a standard view model in a controller using [Route Hijacking](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers).

Obviously its your job to create and maintain these view models, but for many this is standard practice whether using Umbraco or not.

Answer (score 0):

As mortenbock says, you can do `@inherits UmbracoViewPage<IArticle>` and then you could actually detect the type by doing `var isReview = Model is Review`

I removed the `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.` part of the models names. It's not necessary, since they are already referenced in Views/Web.config.

Comment: This is more appropriate for a comment on mortenbock's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the interface for the model and then use `is` and `as` to check for the types and act accordingly.